# Explanation of WP_Query

Tags: wp-query

Why am I able to use WP_Query methods without using an object of this class? Sometimes I see examples that are using the object:

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}
```

But sometimes I don't use it. I just use the_post(), etc without using a WP_Query object.

Comment: Best explained in **[HERE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)**

Comment: ^^ Rarst's answer to that question is a classic but does not directly answer this question.

Comment: It was still very helpful :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `WP_Query` object, you just don't know it (yet).

WordPress generates a `global` called `$wp_query` which is `WP_Query` object. This object is what is responsible for what is called the "main Loop" colloquially. This `$wp_query` object is present on every page that I am aware of. Functions like `the_post`, `have_posts`, and some others, assume the `$wp_query` object. Take a look at [the source for one of them](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/query.php#L775):

```
775 /**
776  * Iterate the post index in the loop.
777  *
778  * @see WP_Query::the_post()
779  * @since 1.5.0
780  * @uses $wp_query
781  */
782 function the_post() {
783         global $wp_query;
784 
785         $wp_query->the_post();
786 }
```

See how the *function* `the_post` simply grabs the `global` `$wp_query` object and then runs `$wp_query->the_post` exactly as happens when you created your own object.

It just so happens that there are *functions* matching the method names of some of the `WP_Query` object. Those are shortcuts to `$wp_query` and you can't use them unless you intend to use `$wp_query`. That is why when you create a new `WP_Query` you have to use the long form-- `$my_query->the_post()`

Answer (score 1):

**You can also follow [WordPress Theme Developer Official Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/)**

In here you will get the appropriate answer to the WP Loop and Query post.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/

Answer (score 0):

Every request for a WordPress page (a page, a post, a category archive, a tag archive, etc.) generates a *main query*, which is stored in the global variable `$wp_query`. When you use `WP_Query` methods without specifying a query object, WordPress uses this global query object. This main query happens before the template is loaded, and the results of that query is how WordPress determines what template to load.

What you have in your example code is a *custom query*, separate from the *main query*. This is used to create queries for additional data aside from the main query. For example, if you want a sidebar with a list of "latest posts" on each page, this would use an additional query. To output that custom query's data, you have to reference the object that you assigned the data to when you made the query.

Answer (score 0):

You use a new object if you want to keep the main query but want to handle a separate query in the same page. From [The Loop Codex examples](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_Example_1):

> If you need to keep the original query around, you can create a new query object.

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=special_cat&posts_per_page=10'); ?>

<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
```